# Pygame window not responding when not refreshing for some time

Tags: python, pygame, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to do some reinforcement learning with a "game" I made.

In my main loop, when I just play my game everything works fine if the window is refreshed regularly.

However, after an episode, I would like to train my agent, but if the training takes too long, the pygame window then only shows the "control bar" (the bar with the X for closing the window) and if I try to close it, the program simply crashes.

Is there a simple way I can deal with it?
Other solutions tell me I should call some pygame function regularly, but if I have to suspend my training just to do it from time to time, the code would become a bit messy.

Answer (score 0):

Reinforcement learning training loops are often defined in a while / for loop with wrappers around the environment and the agent.

A popular design is to wrap the game in the OpenAI gym and call step function with action as input, retrieving next state, reward, terminal state and additional statistics during that time step:

Example:

```
EPISODES = 100
env = gym.make("CartPole-v1")
for i in range(EPISODES):
    state = env.reset()
    steps = 0
    terminal = False
    while terminal is False:
        action = agent.sample(state)
        state, reward, terminal, info = env.step(action)

        if episode > 0:
            agent.train()
```

I assume you do not have your environment gym wrapped, but its quite easy to do so. You can also create your custom code, but the general flow of the application should be as depicted in the example code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to call `pygame.event.get` regularly; otherwise the event queue will fill up and your window will stop responsing.

If you have to run a long running task in your game, you have the following options:

### You a coroutine

If your long running task can be broken up into smaller, fast steps, you can use a cooroutine to give the control back your main loop using yield:

```
import pygame
import time

def long_running_task():
    i = 0
    while i < 300:
        time.sleep(0.01)
        print(i)
        i += 1
        yield i

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    rect = pygame.Rect((10, 250, 32, 32))
    direction = 1
    generator = None
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    generator = long_running_task()

        screen.fill(pygame.Color('darkgrey'))
        rect.move_ip(5 if direction else -5, 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('dodgerblue'), rect)
        if not screen.get_rect().contains(rect):
            direction = not direction

        if generator:
            try: next(generator)
            except StopIteration: generator = None

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This may or may not work you, but it's a nice solution when you have an algorithm that calculates a result and you want to draw your screen in between steps of that algorithm.

### Run your task in another thread or process

Python makes it quite easy to run a function in another process. Here's a simple example using the `multiprocessing` package.

```
import pygame
import time
import multiprocessing

def long_running_task():
    i = 0
    while i < 50:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print(i)
        i += 1
    return i

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    rect = pygame.Rect((10, 250, 32, 32))
    direction = 1
    process = None
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                if process:
                    process.terminate()
                    process.join()
                return
            if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=long_running_task) 
                    process.start()

        screen.fill(pygame.Color('darkgrey'))
        rect.move_ip(5 if direction else -5, 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('dodgerblue'), rect)
        if not screen.get_rect().contains(rect):
            direction = not direction

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```